# How do you type old or uncommon kanji in the Microsoft Windows 8 Japanese IME?

Tags: windows-8, ime, japanese

I am trying to write out a Basho haiku. When converting using the IME, some words that are in hiragana get changed to kanji and some that have kanji don't get changed, like the 切れ字　”かな” that didn't get changed to "哉" without my having to scroll through the extra kanji far beyond the initial choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Forcing the input

The IME is programmed with modern Japanese usage patterns.  Basho is not modern, and his poems use outdated and poetic spellings.

- To input **kana** without conversion, type the romaji, make sure they're converted to the expected kana, then hit Enter to leave these kana unconverted (i.e. not converted to kanji).
- To input irregular **kanji**, you'll just have to sort through the lists.  If the kanji in question is odd enough and uses a sufficiently non-standard reading, you might have to enter the standard reading for it even if that doesn't match what Basho intended.  If you don't know even the reading for a kanji, it might be faster to use the handwriting pad and input it that way.